# Команда sudo не работает в Git Bash на винде

Tags: bash, sudo, git-bash

отвечает так:

```sh
$ sudo
bash: sudo: command not found
```

Comment: Для чего вам там понадобилась эта команда???

Comment: чтобы отредактировать docker контейнер

Comment: sudo vi /etc/hosts

Comment: Делайте без судо. какое отношение к этому имеет гит? Вообще непонятно. У вас контейнер прямо в окружении гит лежит?

Comment: @Эникейщик вово, прям stranger things какой то..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускайте без sudo. В винде применение sudo вобщем и целом малоосмысленно.